# Java Script with width and height

Tags: javascript

i new to js and stumbled on my first and very simple problem, which i cant solve.

I'm making a simple website (with an online editor), and wanted to add a shoutbox. i got one from shoutbox.com

to use it i have to embed it in a html-box which works just fine. The Problem is, that a horizontal scrollbar apears at the html box. i want it gone. i tried with html body codes to hide it, didnt work. making the html-box bigger just streches the shoutbox, the scrollbar is staying.

the width of the shoutbox ist set to 100% and the height to 360px
on shoutbox.com is a faq to change both, but it only shows half, i dont know where to put.

here is the code for the Shoutbox:

```
<script src="https://www.shoutbox.com/chat/chat.js.php"></script><script> var chat = new Chat(112308);  </script></body></style>
```

the faq says:

To change the width: embed the chat into a  element with the width of your choice.

To change the height: over ride .shoutBoxContainer CSS

and gives an example:

```
var chat = new Chat(5, "John"); <style> .shoutBoxContainer {height:450px;} </style>
```

i wanted to make the shoutbox to width 90% to see if this solves the problem.

my Question: How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a css file all you have to do is add to the bottom of the file.

```
.shoutBoxContainer {
   height:450px;
   width:90%;
}
```

if you dont, you add it in a style tag to the `<head>`
without a css file your code will look like this:

```
<head>
<script src="https://www.shoutbox.com/chat/chat.js.php"></script>
<style> 
   .shoutBoxContainer {
      height:450px;
      width:90%;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <script> var chat = new Chat(112308);  </script>
</body>
```

make sure your css is loaded after chat.js.php file.

Comment: The second solution worked perfect. Thank you very much!